# Clarify to understand C variables

Tags: c

I am a newbie and trying to understand program in C.
In the program, there is one header file `typedef.h` which declares `typedef struct { int i; char b;} rdi;`

Then there are 3 folders and each folder has several programs that do a particular task and each folder has one header file. In the header file of each 3 folders it has

```
#include typfedef.h
```

and then declared

```
extern rdi *rdi_x;
```

In all 3 folders it did it. But I do not see it any where in the program defined:

```
  rdi rdi_x;
```

My question is whether it is not required to define `rdi rdi_x;` in the program.

As I understand from c text books, somewhere in the program it needs to define `rdi rdi_x;` or my understanding is not good.

Comment: True, R Sahu.  But is it not a definition.    (A definition is also a declaration).

Comment: @Peter, no. it is not a definition. It will be definition under two circumstances: 1. It is also initialized. `extern rdi *rdi_x = NULL;`. 2. The `extern` keyword is not used. `rdi *rdix_x;`.

Comment: `rdi rdi_x;` would be an error, the definition must match the declaration, `rdi *rdi_x;`

Comment: Why are you looking for `rdi rdi_x;`? The declaration you quoted declares `rdi *rdi_x;`. That's the definition you should be looking for.

Comment: Did you mean to say `typedef.h` instead of `typfedef.h`? Might need to edit that out to prevent confusion

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the presence of a (non-const) `extern` variable in your program is a very strong indication of poor program design. Using `extern` is bad programming practice and should be avoided.

Comment: @Addison: True - and also it should probably also be `#include "typedef.h"` or `#include <typedef.h>` rather than just `#include typedef.h` :-)

Answer (score 10):

> As I understand from c text book, somewhere in the program it needs to define `rdi rdi_x;` or my understanding is not good.

You need to define `rdi_x` only if it is used. Just declaring the variable does not require that it be defined.

Take a much simpler case of one .c file:

Program that fails to build:

```
extern int i;
extern int j;
extern int k;

int main()
{
   k = 10;
}
```

This program will fail to build since `k` is used. If we provide the definition of just `k`, it will build just fine.

Program that builds successfully:

```
extern int i;
extern int j;
extern int k;

int main()
{
   k = 10;
}

int k;
```

Here, `i`, and `j` are declared but not used. Hence, they need not be defined.

Comment: The variable rdi_x is used in many times in the program. That is why I am confused.

Comment: @abbc, that seems strange. My suggestion for you is to try to reduce the program to a [mcve]. It's very likely that you will understand the issue more clearly in the process.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the `#include` in the three source files will be `#include "typfedef.h"`, not `#include typfedef.h`.   The double quotes are required.

Second, `extern rdi *rdi_x` is a declaration, but not a definition.   It can be repeated in any number of source files (or in header files), and will never result in `rdi_x` being defined.

It is necessary to also create a corresponding definition, for example providing the same declaration without the `extern` keyword, viz.

```
 rdi *rdi_x;
```

Note the `*` is still present.  Your description incorrectly suggests that a definition `rdi rdi_x;` (leaving out the `*`) is required.

Bear in mind that, formally, a definition is a type of declaration.    The `extern rdi *rdi_x` is a declaration but not a definition - which is why it can be repeated.   The declaration `rdi *rdi_x` is a corresponding definition - and is subject to the "one definition rule" - in other words, such a definition must be supplied once (and only once) among all compilation units in a project.

Comment: The one-definition rule is a part of C++, not of C, IIRC.

Comment: The include is my typo.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad.   True, but there are rules in the C standard that have the same net effect.   One example pertinent to this case is in the 1999 C standard, Section J.2 "Undefined Behaviour", para 1 (which starts with "The behaviour is defined in the following circumstances:").  The 78th unnumbered bullet point  after that opening line says "An identifier with external linkage is used, but in the program there does not exist
exactly one external definition for the identifier, or the identifier is not used and there exist multiple external definitions for the identifier (6.9)."

Answer (score 2):

If you use an external class library or function library, that library might have a definition of that variable (and is responsible for allocating the memory for it).
Thus all declarations are resolved by the linker when linking your code using that declaration with the definition from the lib you use.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use **#include**, it is like you are inserting the code from the header file into your program.

For that reason, if it has been declared in your header file typedef.h then it should not be necessary to declare in the class including the header.

Now defining is another story, as mentioned by another answer, it depends on how you want to use it

Comment: The variable is used many times in the program, that is why I am confused.

Comment: If it is used in the program and it does not crash, it means that it has already been declared and defined, otherwise something really sketchy is going on. I cannot tell exactly what without seeing all of the classes, but pls upvote if it helped a little!